# How to send to only one client and not all clients using Go and gorilla websocket

Tags: go, websocket

I am trying to learn websockets with Go. I have been looking at examples with gorilla websocket.

I have checked out these 2 examples that show how to use gorilla websocket:

https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/tree/master/examples

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ysAZ_oqPOo0

All of these examples show how to connect to a websocket server, send and receive texts. But what I don't understand is how you can send to only one client. Because in a real world application you will have users, and we don't want all users to receive the same message and same data. Is there a way for me to get the unique id of a connection which I can save in a database like redis and link it to a user id in the same database, and then use that websocket id to send back to a specific client if that user id received a message or a notification? Is this how one would go about and achieve something like this? If that is the case, how would I that?

Comment: Change the Gorilla hub field from ` connections map[*connection]bool` to `connections map[string]*connection` where the string key is the id. Add a `id string` field to connection. Assign id when connection is created and minor changes for map type. Done.

Comment: I agree with @BravadaZadada. There are complex ways to accomplish this, but your need is basic. Just assign any new websocket.Connection a unique key in your map, and when you are ready to write to it call mapname["clientname"].WriteMessage(1, []byte(msg))

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way for me to get the unique id of a connection which I can
>   save in a database like redis and link it to a user id in the same
>   database, and then use that websocket id to send back to a specific
>   client if that user id received a message or a notification?

Sure! You can generate Id by yourself while user registering. Just add userId field in `connection` structure

In chat example you have hub, which contains connections pool. That pool is using to broadcast messages to all users:

```
case m := <-h.broadcast:
    for c := range h.connections {
        select {
        case c.send <- m:
        default:
            close(c.send)
            delete(h.connections, c)
        }
    }
}
```

So there you go. You should make method to send private message, depend on userId