# Websockets with gorilla/websocket for user notifications

Tags: javascript, go

I'm trying to implement websockets with gorilla/websocket package. I followed this example and it worked: https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/tree/master/examples/chat
However I'm trying to send message to particular user, based on user_id.

JS (vue.js) code (simplified):

```
 data() {
        return {
            user_id: 2,
            username: "test",
            userWebSocket: ""
        }
    },
 connectUserToWebSocket() {
        if (window.WebSocket) {
            var loc = window.location;
            var uri = 'ws:';

            if (loc.protocol === 'https:') {
                uri = 'wss:';
            }
            uri += '//localhost:8000/api/ws';


            this.userWebSocket = new WebSocket(uri)

            this.userWebSocket.onopen = function() {
                console.log('Connected')
            }

            this.userWebSocket.onmessage = function(evt) {
                alert(evt.data)
            }
        }
    }
```

And main.go (simplified):

```
import (
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/urfave/negroni"
    "test/notifications"
)

func Router() http.Handler {
  r := mux.NewRouter()

  hub := notifications.NewHub()
  go hub.Run()

  r.HandleFunc("/", controller.Root).Methods("GET")

  //r.HandleFunc("/api/ws", notifications.HandleConnections)
  r.HandleFunc("/api/ws", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    notifications.ServeWs(hub, w, r)
  })
```

And notifications.go:
    package notifications

```
import (
  "net/http"
  "log"
  "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
  "time"
  "bytes"
  "fmt"
)

const (
  // Time allowed to write a message to the peer.
  writeWait = 10 * time.Second

  // Time allowed to read the next pong message from the peer.
  pongWait = 60 * time.Second

  // Send pings to peer with this period. Must be less than pongWait.
  pingPeriod = (pongWait * 9) / 10

  // Maximum message size allowed from peer.
  maxMessageSize = 512
)

var (
  newline = []byte{'\n'}
  space   = []byte{' '}
)

var upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{
 ReadBufferSize:  1024,
 WriteBufferSize: 1024,
 CheckOrigin: func(r *http.Request) bool {
    return true
 },
}


type Client struct {
  hub *Hub

  Id int

  // The websocket connection.
  conn *websocket.Conn

  // Buffered channel of outbound messages.
  send chan []byte
}

type Hub struct {
  // Registered clients.
  clients map[*Client]bool

  users map[int]*Client

  // Inbound messages from the clients.
  broadcast chan []byte

  // Register requests from the clients.
  register chan *Client

  // Unregister requests from clients.
  unregister chan *Client
}

func NewHub() *Hub {
  return &Hub{
    broadcast:  make(chan []byte),
    register:   make(chan *Client),
    unregister: make(chan *Client),
    clients:    make(map[*Client]bool),
    users:      make(map[int]*Client),
 }
}

func (h *Hub) Run() {
 for {
    select {
    case client := <-h.register:
        h.clients[client] = true
    case client := <-h.unregister:
        if _, ok := h.clients[client]; ok {
            delete(h.clients, client)
            close(client.send)
        }
    case message := <-h.broadcast:
        for client := range h.clients {
            select {
            case client.send <- message:
            default:
                close(client.send)
                delete(h.clients, client)
            }
        }
    }
 }
}

// readPump pumps messages from the websocket connection to the hub.
//
// The application runs readPump in a per-connection goroutine. The    application
// ensures that there is at most one reader on a connection by executing all
// reads from this goroutine.
func (c *Client) readPump() {
 defer func() {
    c.hub.unregister <- c
    c.conn.Close()
}()
c.conn.SetReadLimit(maxMessageSize)
c.conn.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(pongWait))
c.conn.SetPongHandler(func(string) error {     c.conn.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(pongWait)); return nil })
for {
    _, message, err := c.conn.ReadMessage()
    if err != nil {
        if websocket.IsUnexpectedCloseError(err, websocket.CloseGoingAway, websocket.CloseAbnormalClosure) {
            log.Printf("error: %v", err)
        }
        break
    }
    message = bytes.TrimSpace(bytes.Replace(message, newline, space, -1))
    c.hub.broadcast <- message
 }
}

// writePump pumps messages from the hub to the websocket connection.
//
// A goroutine running writePump is started for each connection. The
// application ensures that there is at most one writer to a connection by
// executing all writes from this goroutine.
func (c *Client) writePump() {
 ticker := time.NewTicker(pingPeriod)
 defer func() {
    ticker.Stop()
    c.conn.Close()
 }()
 for {
    select {
    case message, ok := <-c.send:
        c.conn.SetWriteDeadline(time.Now().Add(writeWait))
        if !ok {
            // The hub closed the channel.
            c.conn.WriteMessage(websocket.CloseMessage, []byte{})
            return
        }

        w, err := c.conn.NextWriter(websocket.TextMessage)
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
        w.Write(message)

        // Add queued chat messages to the current websocket message.
        n := len(c.send)
        for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
            w.Write(newline)
            w.Write(<-c.send)
        }

        if err := w.Close(); err != nil {
            return
        }
    case <-ticker.C:
        c.conn.SetWriteDeadline(time.Now().Add(writeWait))
        if err := c.conn.WriteMessage(websocket.PingMessage, nil); err !=    nil {
            return
        }
    }
 }
}

// serveWs handles websocket requests from the peer.
func ServeWs(hub *Hub, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  conn, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    log.Println(err)
    return
  }
  client := &Client{hub: hub, conn: conn, send: make(chan []byte, 256)}
  client.hub.register <- client

  // Allow collection of memory referenced by the caller by doing all work in
  // new goroutines.
  go client.writePump()
  go client.readPump()
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to add user_id from JS to connection. Also I would like to keep it safe.

As you may notice, I tried things like:

```
type Client struct {
  ...
  Id int
}
```

And:

```
type Hub struct {
  // Registered clients.
  clients map[*Client]bool

  users map[int]*Client
  ...
}
```

And:

```
func NewHub() *Hub {
  return &Hub{
    ...
    clients:    make(map[*Client]bool),
    users:      make(map[int]*Client),
  }
}
```

But I still don't know how to open websocket with user_id.

TL:DR
1. I've got working code to send notifications to all users.
2. I would like to send notifications to particular users based on ID.

Similar question where there was no help at all:
[How to send to only one client and not all clients using Go and gorilla websocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31598147/how-to-send-to-only-one-client-and-not-all-clients-using-go-and-gorilla-websocke)

Comment: You can just send an instruction to the client (browser/js) asking it to "initialize the conversation" i.e. to provide username/uid. The client then send the required data back. You will need to create data structures and it seems json will do the job well.

Comment: Pass user id along with message to hub. Modify hub to send message with user id to that user only.   See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46415206/golang-one-to-one-chat

Comment: I won't have any message sent by user actually. All I want is notification system, so only server will return some data to user.

Comment: To send to specific user, lookup user in `users` and sent to that user only.   I may not understand the question because this seems somewhat obvious.

Comment: But to look up in users, firstly I should add user to users with specific ID during opening websocket. As you may read it is the problem.

Comment: Use the code you use to identify a user with a plain HTTP request in the websocket handler.  Set the client Id field as appropriate.

Comment: Hi, Using the same code as above i am not receiving the ping messages. `w.conn.SetWriteDeadline(time.Now().Add(writeWait))
w.coon.WriteMessage(websocket.PingMessage, []byte{})` can you please help. And also how did you send the pong reply from javascript

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do the same thing, send system notifications. I used this example and modified it to my needs: https://github.com/AnupKumarPanwar/Golang-realtime-chat-rooms

When a device connects to the websocket also send the user id, something like this:
ws://localhost:8081/ws/connect/{userID} or whatever your url is. You can do user name and then do a user id look up on the server or just use the user name as the "room id"

then add that user to the room:

```
// serveWs handles websocket requests from the peer.
func serveWs(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    vars := mux.Vars(r)

    upgrader.CheckOrigin = func(r *http.Request) bool { return true }
    ws, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err.Error())
        return
    }
    c := &connection{send: make(chan []byte, 256), ws: ws}
    s := subscription{c, vars["userID"]}
    h.register <- s
    go s.writePump()
    go s.readPump()
}
```

The "s := subscription{c, vars["userID"]}" is how you create a specific "room" in your case with the user id.

To broadcast a message to that room just have something like this:

```
func NewNotification(userID string, msg []byte) error {
    m := message{msg, userID}
    h.broadcast <- m
    return nil
}
```

have your notification call that function to broadcast to the room.

Hope that makes sense!