# Sending a Websocket message to a specific client in Go (using Gorilla)

Tags: go, websocket, gorilla

I am very new to Go and have found myself working with sockets as my first project. This is a redundant question, but I have failed to understand how 
to send a websocket update to a specific client in Go (using Gorilla).

The broad problem that I am trying to solve is - Building a typeahead using websockets and a search engine like ES/Lucene. I have maintained a bunch of indexes on my search engine and have a Go wrapper around it. When I started working on using websockets in Go, I have been finding almost all the examples showing broadcasting mechanism. When I tried to dig into this and tried to modify the example given in Gorilla's github [repo](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/tree/master/examples/chat) based on the examples given in [this](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/issues/46) thread and in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31598147/how-to-send-to-only-one-client-and-not-all-clients-using-go-and-gorilla-websocke), I don't seem to understand `connections` and how does that fit in `client.go`

Ideally, the way I would like to see this working is -

- A socket connection between the client and server is established
- Upon the client sending inputs via the socket, the server fetches it and throws into into a channel (Go channel)
- The indexing wrapper checks for this channel, and once there is something to fetch, the index is retrieved and written back to the socket

How can the server uniquely identify the `Client`?

I have used the examples given on Gorilla's Github [repo](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/tree/master/examples/chat)

From my codebase `hub.go` has the following

```
type Hub struct {
    // Registered clients.
    clients map[*Client]bool

    // Inbound messages from the clients.
    broadcast chan []byte

    // Register requests from the clients.
    register chan *Client

    // Unregister requests from clients.
    unregister chan *Client

    connections map[string]*connection
}

func newHub() *Hub {
    return &Hub{
        broadcast:  make(chan []byte),
        register:   make(chan *Client),
        unregister: make(chan *Client),
        clients:    make(map[*Client]bool),
        connection: make(map[*Client]bool), // is this alright?
    }
}

func (h *Hub) run() {
    for {
        select {
        case client := <-h.register:
            h.clients[client] = true
        case client := <-h.unregister:
            if _, ok := h.clients[client]; ok {
                delete(h.clients, client)
                close(client.send)
            }
        case message := <-h.broadcast:
            for client := range h.connections {
                select {
                case client.send <- message:
                default:
                    close(client.send)
                    delete(h.connections, client)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I am unsure with what I should be adding to `client.go`

```
type Client struct {
    // unique ID for each client
    // id string

    // Hub object
    hub *Hub

    // The websocket connection.
    conn *websocket.Conn

    // Buffered channel of outbound messages.
    send chan []byte

    // connection --> (what should the connection property be?)
    connection string
}
```

Please note - I will be adding an `Id` field within the `Client` struct. How can I proceed from here?

Comment: The problem is finding the `*Client`

Comment: Should I maintain a map of the clients in a DB? Doesn't the `Client` struct have the required things to identify a client uniquely?

Comment: @ThunderCat Thank you for the suggestion, hopefully this edit makes thing a little clearer

Comment: Ah, let me take a look at that example once. Will update on this thread shortly. Thank you @ThunderCat

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The chat example shows how to implement broadcast. The chat example is not a good starting point for an application if broadcast is not required.

To send a message to a specific websocket connection, simply write to the connection using [NextWriter](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/websocket#Conn.NextWriter) or [WriteMessage](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/websocket#Conn.WriteMessage). These methods do not support concurrent writers, so you may need to use a mutex or goroutine to ensure a single writer.

The simple approach for finding a specific `*websocket.Connection` is to pass `*websocket.Connection` to the code that needs it. If the application needs to associate other state with a connection, then define a type to hold that state and pass a pointer to that around:

```
type Client struct {
    conn *websocket.Conn
    mu sync.Mutex
    ...
}
```

The `Hub` can be modified to send messages to specific connection, but it's a roundabout path if broadcast is not needed. Here's how to do it:

Add ID field to client:

```
 ID idType // replace idType with int, string, or whatever you want to use
```

Change the Gorilla hub field from `connections map[*connection]bool` to `connections map[idType]*connection`.

Define a message type containing the message data and the ID of the target client:

```
type message struct {
   ID idtype
   data []byte
}
```

Replace the hub broadcast field with:

```
   send chan message
```

Change the hub for loop to:

```
for {
    select {
    case client := <-h.register:
        h.clients[client.ID] = client
    case client := <-h.unregister:
        if _, ok := h.clients[client.ID]; ok {
            delete(h.clients, client.ID)
            close(client.send)
        }
    case message := <-h.send:
        if client, ok := h.clients[message.ID]; ok {
            select {
            case client.send <- message.data:
            default:
                close(client.send)
                delete(h.connections, client)
            }
        }
    }
```

Send messages to a specific client by creating a `message` with the appropriate ID:

```
   hub.send <- message{ID: targetID, data: data}
```

Comment: Good stuff, I was able to implement 1:1 bidirectional communication between multiple clients and one server based of your post, thanks!