# Selectively send event to particular clients

Tags: go, client, server-sent-events, go-gin

I am building a gin application where I am utilizing SSE to notify my user of any relevant changes to the database based on [this tutorial](https://github.com/gin-gonic/examples/blob/master/server-sent-event/main.go). Currently, I have implemented the functionality such that during a POST handler sends a message via a channel to the GET handler to trigger an event send for all clients. The end point is `/events/:uid/` where uid refers to a param variable which would be the client's UID that I set. My question is that I am confused as to how to broadcast the SSE to a certain group of users who are each listening on their own unique endpoint. Right now all clients are added to a map however I am unsure as to how to filter based on that.

**GET endpoint handler**

```
var eventsStream = broker.NewServer()

func GetRelevantMarkers(c *gin.Context) {
    c.Writer.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/event-stream")
    c.Writer.Header().Set("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
    c.Writer.Header().Set("Connection", "keep-alive")
    c.Writer.Header().Set("Transfer-Encoding", "chunked")

    clientChan := make(broker.ClientChan)

    // Send new connection to event server
    eventsStream.NewClients <- clientChan

    defer func() {
        // Send closed connection to event server
        eventsStream.ClosedClients <- clientChan
    }()

    go func() {
        // Send connection that is closed by client to event server
        <-c.Done()
        eventsStream.ClosedClients <- clientChan
    }()


    c.Stream(func(w io.Writer) bool {
        // Stream message to client from message channel
        if msg, ok := <-eventsStream.Message; ok {
            c.SSEvent("message", msg)
            return true
        }
        return false
    })
}
```

**Event Broker**

```
type Event struct {
    // Events are pushed to this channel by the main events-gathering routine
    Message chan string

    // New client connections
    NewClients chan chan string

    // Closed client connections
    ClosedClients chan chan string

    // Total client connections
    TotalClients map[chan string]bool
}

type ClientChan chan string

func NewServer() (event *Event) {

    event = &Event{
        Message:       make(chan string),
        NewClients:    make(chan chan string),
        ClosedClients: make(chan chan string),
        TotalClients:  make(map[chan string]bool),
    }

    go event.listen()

    return
}

func (stream *Event) listen() {
    for {
        select {
        // Add new available client
        case client := <-stream.NewClients:
            stream.TotalClients[client] = true
            log.Printf("Client added. %d registered clients", len(stream.TotalClients))

        // Remove closed client
        case client := <-stream.ClosedClients:
            delete(stream.TotalClients, client)
            log.Printf("Removed client. %d registered clients", len(stream.TotalClients))

        // Broadcast message to client
        case eventMsg := <-stream.Message:
            for clientMessageChan := range stream.TotalClients {
                clientMessageChan <- eventMsg
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**POST endpoint handler**

```
func DeleteEvent(c *gin.Context) {
    eventsStream.Message <- "event-deleted"
}
```

Comment: Does [Sending a Websocket message to a specific channel in Go (using Gorilla)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57810457/5728991) answer your question?  The question is regarding websockets, but the relevant code is nearly identical. Replace `roomID` with the uid in your application.

Comment: @CeriseLimón With the exception of the message property, I have turned all `chan string` to `chan *Client` and have updated my loop as so `for clientMessageChan := range stream.TotalClients {if strings.Contains(eventMsg, "public") || strings.Contains(eventMsg, clientMessageChan.UID) {
clientMessageChan.Send <- eventMsg
}else{
clientMessageChan.Send <- "Cant send"
}
}`. . I have passed in the case _"event-created/private"_ in order to get an output of _"Can't send"_ however the string _"event-created/private"_ is always being sent to client

Comment: See answer linked from my previous comment.  Change `chan string` to `chan message`.  Change `chan chan string` to `chan *client`.  Filter using message.roomID and client.roomID.

Comment: @CeriseLimón I believe the only difference between the attached answer and mine is that I am sending a string that contains both the event and the details I need to about who to send it to which is extracted in my `strings.Contains` portion whereas the attached answer has transformed that into the struct - would the struct transport provide any advantage over string transport?

Comment: strings.Contains will have a false positive when the message data happens to contain a sequence of bytes that matches your metadata filter.  Keep the metadata separate from the data.

Comment: @CeriseLimón I have taken your advice and updated my GET handler to `eventsStream.Message <- broker.Message{Data: "event-created",IsPrivate: false, Clients: []*broker.Client{},}` and the new message case to this `if eventMsg.IsPrivate {
for _,clientMessageChan := range eventMsg.Clients {clientMessageChan.Send <-eventMsg.Data}}else{for clientMessageChan := range stream.TotalClients {clientMessageChan.Send <- eventMsg.Data}}` and I am still getting behavior of one client getting updated during one POST and the other client during the other POST. Now the data output is the full struct

Comment: @CeriseLimón with regards to the code I attached which is influenced by the tutorial I sent, the last case in the listen function doesn't get triggered nor does it provide any use as the data in clientMessageChan is not being sent anywhere and there is a direct listener in the GET handler, such that whenever a new message is streamed from POST, the SSE event is triggered for all clients. Right now with the advice you gave, I am able to create clients and assign them unique channels so how would I take the message data that flows through a client's channel and send the event to only that cliend

Answer (score 1):

i know this is 1 year late, but i found the solution to your problem as i was experimenting on how to send SSE in Golang and implement RabbitMQ

This is my oversimplified solution.

I was using echo framework but you could adjust the code to match your own framework.
**The GET url to connect to event**

```
e.GET("/api-gateway/stream/:id", handlers.SseStream)
```

The GET method to open connection to the server could use JWT with id payload instead of using the id parameters

**Sending consumed message from RabbitMQ to the client**

```
receiver := make(chan bool)
go func() {

    var eventMessage string
    for message := range messages {
        log.Printf("\tReceived message: %s\n", message.Body)
        log.Printf("\tCorrelation ID: %s\n", message.CorrelationId)

        eventMessage = fmt.Sprintf("id: %d\nevent: %s\ndata: %s\n\n", message.DeliveryTag, message.Headers["event"], message.Body)

        _, exists := handlers.Client["2"]
        if exists {
           // the key is hardcoded but you could make it so that the message from RabbitMQ contains the user id too to replace the key
            handlers.Client["2"] <- eventMessage
        } else {
            log.Print("client id 2 doesn't exists")
        }
    }
}()
<-receiver
```

**the SSE handler**

```
// Create a client map to store connected clients
var Client map[string]chan string = make(map[string]chan string)

// setup event stream header and 200 status code
func prepareHeaderForSSE(c echo.Context) {
    c.Response().Writer.Header().Add(echo.HeaderContentType, "text/event-stream")
    c.Response().Writer.Header().Add(echo.HeaderCacheControl, "no-cache")
    c.Response().Writer.Header().Add(echo.HeaderConnection, "keep-alive")
    c.Response().Writer.Header().Add(echo.HeaderAccessControlAllowOrigin, "*")
    c.Response().WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
}

// This is the main SSE handler function when user want to connect to events
func SseStream(c echo.Context) error {
    log.Print("Connected to event")
    id := c.Param("id")

    log.Print(id)
    prepareHeaderForSSE(c)
    Client[c.Param("id")] = make(chan string)
    defer func() {
        close(Client[id])
        delete(Client, "1")
        log.Printf("Closing client %s", id)
    }()

   // infinite loop to write event
    for {
        write, err := fmt.Fprintf(c.Response().Writer, <-Client[id])
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }
        log.Print(write)

        c.Response().Flush()
    }
}

func SseMessage(message string) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        if MessageChan != nil {
            MessageChan <- message
        }
    }
}
```

another method to send message to specific clients from the code above if you are not implementing rabbitMQ is to send bearer token or other authorization method when you do POST/PUT/DELETE request, then your server could get the id or other unique identifier that could be used as the key.

**What if the user is not authenticated?**
You could still add a unique key for the unauthenticated user and use that

I know the code is bad, but i hope it gives you idea on how to do it